# How can I use functions from other files while using the same variables in the main file?

Tags: python, function, file, variables, tkinter

I want to know if I can use functions from other file, but the function in the other file has variables from the main one.

For example I have this function in another file but it doesnt know what ans_num is from the main file:

```
def delete(type):
if type == "all":
    ans_num.delete(0, END)
    ans_den.delete(0, END)
elif type == "first":
    ans_num.delete(0)
    ans_den.delete(0)
```

Ive tried using parameters as references:

```
def delete(type, refer_ans_num, refer_ans_den, END):
if type == "all":
    refer_ans_num.delete(0, END)
    refer_ans_den.delete(0, END)
elif type == "first":
    refer_ans_num.delete(0)
    refer_ans_den.delete(0)
```

In main file:

```
delete("all", ans_num, ans_den, END)
```

but I was interested if there could be a more effective solution.

Comment: That is correct. You are following the DRY Principle.... COngrats

Comment: Agreed. Using parameters is the correct way of doing this.You can also make a class for "ans" which has its own "num", "den" and "delete".

Comment: second version gives less problems and you may spend less time on debugins - so it is `more effective solution`

Comment: more "effective" would be to keep all in one file. if you have function specailly create for some widget then it could be good to have it one file. And if you know how to use classes then you could use it to create own widgets with its function and this keep in separted file.

Comment: Oh ok thanks because this project is meant to be a calculator with almost any math function, and this is a fraction calculator so the file was going to be huge.